# How to call a same modal with empty form what i have edited row data on a table row Click?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd, formik, yup

i am getting data in antd table using json data.Now click on a table row iam getting the data in a Modal.Now i want to call same modal on click on register button with empty data?

Here my sample data for StudentTable

```
 showModal = () => {

        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    }

    onOk = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        })

    }

    onCancel = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            visible: false
        })
    }


    rowClick = (record, rowIndex) => {
        alert("student id...." + record.id)
        alert(JSON.stringify(record))
        this.showModal();
        this.setState({
            StudentData: record
        })


    }

    render() {


        return (

            <div>
                <div align="right">
                <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>Register</Button>
                </div>
                <h2>Student Data</h2>
                <Table
                    dataSource={data}
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
                    rowKey={record => record.id}
                    onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
                        return {
                            onClick: (event) => this.rowClick(record, rowIndex)
                        }
                    }}

                />
                <NewModal visible={this.state.visible}
                    onOk={this.onOk}
                    onCancel={this.onCancel}
                    StudentData={this.state.StudentData}
                />


            </div>

        )
    }
```

i have a NewModal. iam getting the data on a table rowClick using mapPropsValues.Now i want to call same Modal with empty data?If i click on a table row call same modal i am getting the data?Now How to get empty form click on Register button using same modal?

my modal has following code?

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    Modal
} from 'antd'
import FormikApollo from "./FormikForm"

class NewModal extends React.Component {

    state = {

        visible: this.props.visible
    }


    render() {
         const { StudentData} = this.props
         console.log(this.props.StudentData)
        return (

            <Modal
                title="Basic Modal"
                visible={this.props.visible}
                onOk={this.props.onOk}
                onCancel={this.props.onCancel}
                onCreate={this.handleCreate}

            >
                <FormikApollo StudentData={this.props.StudentData}/>
            </Modal>

        )
    }

}

export default NewModal
```

And iam getting the form data using formik with antd component.Now i want to call same modal what i get click on a table row with empty form click on a register button?

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Row gutter={4}>
                        <Col span={12} push={5}>
                            <Field
                                name="id"
                                label="StudentID"
                                placeholder="Enter a Id"
                                component={AntInput}                                
                                type="text"                                
                                formitemlayout={formItemLayout}

                            />

                            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>

                </Form>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

const FormikApp = (withFormik)({

    mapPropsToValues: ({StudentData}) => ({
        ...(StudentData)
    }),        

    validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
        username: Yup.string()
            .min(3, "Username must be above 3 characters")
            .required("Username is required"),
        email: Yup.string()
            .email("Invalid Email !!")
            .required("Email is required"),
        password: Yup.string()
            .min(6, "Password must be above 6 characters")
            .required("Password is required"),

        dateofbirth: Yup.string().required("Date is required")



    }),
    handleSubmit(values,{resetForm}) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values))
        console.log(values)

    }

})(FormikApollo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render the Modal component again, upon the click of a button I would suggest you would render if conditionally.

So you could have a state like this

`state={showModal: false}` or `state={isSubmitted: false}`

And then in your jsx code something like this where you set the state to the opposite of the previous state, to show/not show the modal

```
<button onClick={e => this.setState(prevState => ({showModal: !prevState.showModal}))}>Submit </button>

{this.state.showModal &&
    <Modal {...props} show={this.state.showModal} />
  }
```

and then you could pass your existing props into your modal, or other props if you need that. Then you pass in the state, that controls rather the modal shows or not into the modal.

EDIT:

after understanding the problem further, there are two ways to solve this issue.

1. Use some middleware like Redux/Thunk to transport data/props to another component located further away from the original component. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk
2. Relocate your props, so that you are able to pass props to your modal component from multiple places (this would require a restructuring of your architecture, therefore I recommend using something like redux.

Comment: thank you for given reply. i am adding the props on a Modal but its not working

Comment: where is your modal located?

Comment: The modal is loaded fine?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: there is no change on my code. iam not getting a modal on a click on button

Comment: When the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Modal is not loaded click on a button

Comment: here my problem is i want to display same model click on a register button. this button is added on top up the modal.My problem is model is displayed but click on register button its shows empty form modal with out data like register form and click on a table row same modal shows on table row data

Comment: so you want the props transferred to the modal, on signup?

Comment: Okay this is a typical issue in react, js when you want some universal props passed to a component allocated, further away.

Comment: ok thank you for your suggestion.is it possible please check it once on my code on codesandbox

Comment: yes, i will have a look at it.. please upvote and accept my answer if it fulfills the initial question

Comment: ok thank you but getting a problem on calling the same modal.i didn't understand how to reset the same form with out data?